# Countdown -> Redirect -> Reset

Tags: php, html, redirect, refresh, countdown

I tried to make a countdown that when finishes redirects to another url (even if i'm not online on page, this page i want to redirect to, does something) then resets countdown.

Here is the countdown:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Countdown</TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

var eventdate = new Date("May 19, 2013 21:00:00");

function toSt(n) {
 s=""
 if(n<10) s+="0"
 return s+n.toString();
}

function countdown() {
 cl=document.clock;
 d=new Date();
 count=Math.floor((eventdate.getTime()-d.getTime())/1000);
 if(count<=0)
   {cl.hours.value="--";
    cl.mins.value="--";
    cl.secs.value="--";
    return;
  }
 cl.secs.value=toSt(count%60);
 count=Math.floor(count/60);
 cl.mins.value=toSt(count%60);
 count=Math.floor(count/60);
 cl.hours.value=count;    

 setTimeout("countdown()",500);
}
// end hiding script-->
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY  onLoad="countdown()">

<FONT FACE="arial, helvetica" SIZE="-1">
<CENTER>
<P>
<FORM name="clock">
         <TD ALIGN=CENTER><INPUT name="hours" size=0></TD> :
         <TD ALIGN=CENTER><INPUT name="mins" size=0></TD> :
         <TD ALIGN=CENTER><INPUT name="secs" size=0></TD>   
         <TD ALIGN=CENTER><B>Hours</B></TD>  
</FORM>
</CENTER>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I have tried somehing like this:

```
    if(count=0){<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=http://www.example.com/">}
```

but it needs to be inserted in the HEAD, and it just redirects
Please help me... You can do this in php, html or any language where this will work.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to reset the countdown if you leave the page anyway? Or do you mean with "reset" setting a different event date? A little bit more information would be helpful.

Comment: if you are not "on" the page then any code on the page will not be running and will not be able to redirect you anywhere.

Comment: +1 for still using the <FONT> tag.

Comment: I'm sorry. For example i want to send a mail every 7 days. i have the page that does it. it just need to be clicked. so when countdown finishes it clicks that and resets the countdown back to 7 days.
You don't have to use mine countdown script. Thank you very much for your responds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For example i want to send a mail every 7 days. i have the page that
>   does it. it just need to be clicked. so when countdown finishes it
>   clicks that and resets the countdown back to 7 days.

I would use Cron Jobs to do that instead of a Jquery code.

But, anyways, in regards of what you were asking, the redirecting stuff, you could use the following code which doesn't need to be placed in `<head>`

```
if(count == 0){
    window.location.href="http://example.com";
}
```